# How to sync the calendars of two exchange accounts of different institutions

Tags: calendar, exchange-2007

I'm working for two companies a.t.m. and in each company I have a separate exchange account (because every company runs its own exchange 2007 server...). Is it possible to automatically synchronize the calendars of both accounts so every time I add a new schedule to the one calendar it is stored to the other calendar as well?

Comment: This will find a better audience on SuperUser, but while you're here it would be a good idea to verify that you're not violating IT policy for either of your companies by doing what you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, but it is a request from my boss because some other colleague have to do this as well

Comment: I have the same situation as a consultant.  I have been using Google Calendar Sync to sync each Exchange calendar to Google calendar, but this has been giving me some issues lately.  It may work for you.  Otherwise, how did you accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Outlook you should be able to setup a rule that auto forwards incoming calendar events to the other account. It's not ideal because appointments you set would still have to be set in both locations. There is probably 3rd party software available to do this too.